# HTMLAgilityPack SelectSingleNode returning null while webscraping genius

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to scrape some simple lyrics from genius with HTMLAgilityPack and sometimes all goes fine, but others the node is just null, I know from analyzing the html of genius.com that every single lyric page has a div with the class "lyrics" but sometimes when I try to select that node with the HTMLAgilityPack it just returns null, even with the same song: I try to execute the program like 10 times with the same html and 2 times it actually loads it, while the other 8 it doesn't. I know i could just add a while loop to check if the node is null but isn't there any better way?

Here's the code:

```
            HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("https://genius.com/song");
            var node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='lyrics']");
            if (node != null)
            {
                string lyrics = node.InnerText.Trim();
                Console.WriteLine(lyrics);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: If it’s null, inspect the HTML you get for a possible reason?

Comment: As I said in the post, the web page always have a div with the class lyrics

Comment: `the web page always have a div with the class lyrics` The Raw HTML does not have that. Check for yourself. `View Source` in the browser.

Comment: Actually i just looked at the source with firefox and the div is always there

Comment: No you didn't. You looked at it in dev tools _once the JS is executed_. Right click in the page and `View Page Source`. It **is not** there.

Comment: I suggest giving https://html-agility-pack.net/from-browser a read